# Using template iterator in C++ std::map

Tags: c++, templates, dictionary, iterator

The goal is to print each k,v pair in a map, using template:

```
template<typename K, typename V>
typedef std::map<K,V>::const_iterator MapIterator;

template<typename K, typename V>
void PrintMap(const std::map<K,V>& m) {
    for (MapIterator iter = m.begin(); iter != m.end(); iter++) {
        std::cout << "Key: " << iter->first << " "
              << "Values: " << iter->second << std::endl;
    }
}
```

However, my compiler says that the expression iter->first could not be resolved, what's the problem?

**EDIT**: I should read compile errors at first, then trying to solve problems by tracing errors. Asking for help without thinking is not a good habit, thanks to @Oli Charlesworth.

```
error: template declaration of ‘typedef’
error: need ‘typename’ before ‘std::map<T1, T2>::const_iterator’ because ‘std::map<T1, T2>’ is a dependent scope
error: ‘MapIterator’ was not declared in this scope
error: expected ‘;’ before ‘iter’
error: ‘iter’ was not declared in this scope
```

**COMPLEMENTS**:
The problem has been discussed in great detail in [Where and why do I have to put the "template" and "typename" keywords?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/610245/where-and-why-do-i-have-to-put-the-template-and-typename-keywords?rq=1). According to @RiaD, there is a trivial solution to this problem as a complement.

```
template<typename K, typename V>
void PrintMap(const std::map<K,V>& m) {
    typedef typename std::map<K,V>::const_iterator MapIterator;
    for (MapIterator iter = m.begin(); iter != m.end(); iter++) {
        std::cout << "Key: " << iter->first << " "
              << "Values: " << iter->second << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: What *exactly* does the compiler say?

Comment: You have taught me a lesson, thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

template `typedef` should not compile. Either use `using` directive or `typedef` inside a class

```
#include <map>
#include <iostream>
template<typename K, typename V>
using MapIterator = typename std::map<K,V>::const_iterator;

template<typename K, typename V>
void PrintMap(const std::map<K,V>& m) {
    for (MapIterator<K, V> iter = m.begin(); iter != m.end(); iter++) {
        std::cout << "Key: " << iter->first << " "
              << "Values: " << iter->second << std::endl;
    }
}

int main() {
    std::map<int, int> x = {{5, 7}, {8, 2}};
    PrintMap(x);
    return 0;
}
```

http://ideone.com/xxdKBQ